# C++ Function return a value and delete it from array

Tags: c++

I have this function:

```
int findnext(int nr,int counter,int v[]){
    int i,newnr=-1;
    for(i = counter-1; i >= 0; i--){
        if(v[i] > nr){
            newnr = v[i];
        }
    }
    if(newnr == -1) return -1;
    else return newnr;
}
```

What this function does is, It finds the next bigger number in an array, and if it cannot find one, it returns -1; What I want to do is, after I use this in my main class like this...

```
int main(){
  int a=1;counter=3;
  int v[3]={-1,2,3}; //v[0] is -1 because a=1
  a = findnext(a,counter,v);
}
```

...to replace v[1] in my main class with -1 (as it found the next big number as a 2) and replace the -1 on v[0] to 1 (what the variable a was before). Is this possible?

Thank you in advance!

Extra info:

1. int v[5] can be {1,1,3,3,4} to begin with (it can have more than one same element)
2. int v[5] can be {1,4,6,7,9} to begin with (not {1,2,3,4,5...})
3. The array is sorted.
4. If the result of the function is -1, then it makes the array go to it's original state
5. The array is never going to have a number that's less than 0 in it.

Example:

The program starts with:
v[5] = {1,6,7,9,9}; and a = -1;

I execute the function: a = 1; v[5]={-1,6,7,9,9};

I execute it again and: a = 6; v[5]={1,-1,7,9,9};

I execute it again and: a = 7; v[5]={1,6,-1,9,9};

I execute it again and: a = 9; v[5]={1,6,7,-1,9};

I execute it again and: a = 9; v[5]={1,6,7,9,-1};

I execute it again and: a = -1; v[5]={1,6,7,9,9);

Comment: Your examples don't seem to match what you are asking for, or what your function does. It seems that your function returns the first value in an array that is higher than the value passed in. (Also, a note, the `if` condition at the end of  your function is unnecessary.)

Comment: Yes, What I was asking is how can I make it so It does what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code. best way to solve this problem is to remember old replaced value and index and replace it back when new changes made.

here i have used c++11 initializer_list to make initialisation little easy.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<sstream>
#include<iterator>
#include<initializer_list>

using namespace std;

template <int t> class Selectable
{

    int index;
    int value;
    int v[t];

public:
    Selectable() : index(-1), value(-1)
    {

    }

    Selectable(initializer_list<int> x) : index(-1), value(-1)
    {
        copy(x.begin(), x.begin() + t, v);
    }

    int selectNext(int n)
    {
        if (index + 1 == t)
        {
            v[index] = value;
            index++;
        }

        cout << endl << index;

        for (int i = index + 1; i < t; i++)
        {
            // cout<<v[i];
            if (v[i] > n)
            {
                if (index >= 0)
                {
                    v[index] = value;
                }

                index = i;
                value = v[i];
                v[i] = -1;

                show();
                return 1;
            }
        }

        show();
        return -1;

    }

    void show()
    {
        copy(v, v + t, ostream_iterator<int>(cout, "\t"));
    }

};

int main()
{
    Selectable<5> s;
    s = {2, 3, 2, 3, 2};

    cout<<s.selectNext(-1)<<endl;
    cout<<s.selectNext(-1)<<endl;
    cout<<s.selectNext(-1)<<endl;
    cout<<s.selectNext(-1)<<endl;
    cout<<s.selectNext(-1)<<endl;
    cout<<s.selectNext(-1)<<endl;
    cout<<s.selectNext(-1)<<endl;
    cout<<s.selectNext(-1)<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for responding to this, I thought noone would! I appreciate it